# Where to put global helper js functions

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have several helper functions I intend to use throughout my Vue.js 2 application (i.e. within components and vuex). The one I'm using as an example here, `toCurrency`, converts a number to a currency string. I'm wondering where the best place to put this helper function is. I'm currently putting it at the top of my `store.js` file (I'm using `vuex` obviously) and calling it throughout the file. However, this means I also need to define it as a `method` when I want to use it in components. Is there a better place to put them so I don't have to keep defining it or is this the best place?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

function toCurrency(num){
    return "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        price: 2
    },
    getters: {
        numString: state => {
            return toCurrency(state.funds)
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        decrementOne: state => {
            state.num --;
            alert("Price decremented to " + toCurrency(state.funds))
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect case for [Instance Variables](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html). Essentially I would firstly setup an address such as `this.$helperfunctions` and then proceed to add all of my methods directly onto this instance member after which they will become available to the rest of your application.

```
import myObjectFullOfMethods from '../somewhere/foo/bar.js';

new Vue({
  beforeCreate: function() {
    this.$helperfunctions = new myObjectFullOfMethods();
  }
})
```

Comment: This looks great. Would I be able to use these in Vuex or do I need to refine them there?

Comment: @JohnnyMetz There available anywhere you import the Vue instance :-) using `this.Vue.$helperfunctions` for example

Comment: is there a way to use it in Vuex.Store modules?. The context of modules is `Store` and no `this.Vue` there..

Comment: Your Vue instance is always in scope of your of the `import Vue from 'Vue'` which will always give you back your main Vue instance inside Vuex.